# UIVIevController overriding

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, overriding

I have some troubles **(error: Method does not override any method from its superclass)**  with overriding UIVC method, what am I doing wrong?

Code example with supportedInterfaceOrientation, which doesn`t cause error, but still not overriding and not working.

```
func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMask(rawValue:(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait.rawValue | UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape.rawValue))}
```

Screenshot problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSXzt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`supportedInterfaceOrientations` is a computed property, not a function:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621435-supportedinterfaceorientations

so error is correct - there is no such function in superclass.

Replace `func` with `var` and `() ->` with `:`

Answer (score 0):

The new versions of the Xcode the method have changed. Now it's a variable that you can override.

```
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { get }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a property. Swift override:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    get {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
    }
}
```